# Why does the slice method include the end argument in this code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, slice, mergesort

I came across this video explaining merge sort in javascript https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppNZ4bmrmGs&t=195s

To my knowledge, the slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, but does *not include*, the given end argument. So how comes when this person is trying to make a variable for a sub-array storing index 0 to the end argument, it includes the end argument? :

```
const leftSide = array.slice(0, middle);
const rightSide = array.slice(middle, array.length);
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```js
const mergeSort = array => {
  //Check if array can be split
  if(array.length < 2) return array;
  //Get Middle index
  const middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
  //Split Array In Two Sides
  const leftSide = array.slice(0, middle);
  const rightSide = array.slice(middle, array.length);
  //Use recusion to continue splitting
  console.log('split:', leftSide, rightSide);
  return merge(mergeSort(leftSide), mergeSort(rightSide));
}

const merge = (left, right) => {
  //Create New Array
  const result = [];
  //Check if left array and right array is empty
  while(left.length && right.length) {
    //Find lower value
    if(left[0] <= right[0]) {
      //Add left value
      result.push(left.shift());
    } else {
      //Add right value
      result.push(right.shift());
    }
  }
  //Merge left array
  while(left.length) result.push(left.shift());
  //Merge right array
  while(right.length) result.push(right.shift());
  //return result array
  console.log('result:', result);
  return result;
}

console.log(mergeSort([5, 3, 7, 10, 4, 1, 5]));
```

Comment: `.length` is the number of items in the array, by starting at 0 length will always be `i+1` for i being the last index.

Answer (score 1):

A result of indices starting at 0 in most coding languages is that you can access the first n elements by taking all the elements whose index is less than n. Most mechanics of coding languages follow this, like the inclusive-exclusive property of functions like `splice`. Take a look at how your test array would be split:

`5 3 7 10 4 1 5`

For lists of even length splitting into 2 is simple; both sides will have the same length. For odd length lists, you have to make the choice of the left side being bigger or the right, and in this implementation right was chosen (thus `floor` was used). Length is 7, so `middle` is set to floor(7/2)=3. That means the left side of the split should have length 3 (so `5 3 7`) and the right side length 4. If you count the indices you find that `7` has index `2`. So if you partition from `0` to `3` inclusive-exclusive, you include everything up to the 3rd element, or the 2nd index, which is what is desired.